# Problema con consulta JPQL + JPA + JSF + EJB

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, ejb, jpql

```
@Override

public Usuario iniciarSesion(Usuario us){

    Usuario usuario = null;
    String consulta;

    try {
        consulta = "FROM usuario u WHERE u.usuario = ?1 and u.password =?2";
        Query query = em.createQuery(consulta);
        query.setParameter(1, us.getUsuario());
        query.setParameter(2, us.getPassword());
        List<Usuario> lista = query.getResultList();
        
        if (!lista.isEmpty()) {
            usuario = lista.get(0);
            
        }
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    
    }
    return usuario;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

obtengo el siguiente error

> Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
>
> Exception Description: Problem compiling [FROM usuario u WHERE u.usuario = ?1 and u.password =?2].
>
> [5, 12] The abstract schema type 'usuario' is unknown.
>
> [21, 30] The state field path 'u.usuario' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
>
> [40, 50] The state field path 'u.password' cannot be resolved to a valid type.

Comment: JPQL, a diferencia de SQL, distingue entre mayúsculas y minúscultas. Pon `Usuario` (que es el nombre correcto de la clase) en lugar de `usuario`

Answer (score 5):

> The abstract schema type 'usuario' is unknown.

En la consulta From usuario u ..., la primera letra de 'usuario' está en minúscula, y en tu entidad es en mayúscula 'Usuario'.

Comment: Sería necesario ver el mapeo de la entidad Usuario para estar seguros. Pero en principio si que parece un error tipográfico.

Comment: ¿Error tipográfico o desconocimiento por parte del OP? En SQL no se distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas a menos que uses comillas dobles en los nombres

Answer (score 1):

Los parámetros deben ser una cadena, prueba a cambiarlos

```
try {
    consulta = "FROM usuario u WHERE u.usuario = :1 and u.password =:2";
    Query query = em.createQuery(consulta);
    query.setParameter("1", us.getUsuario());
    query.setParameter("2", us.getPassword());
    List<Usuario> lista = query.getResultList();

    if (!lista.isEmpty()) {
        usuario = lista.get(0);

    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;

}
```